# Count occurrences of multiple columns as total

Tags: sql

First post here... :)

What I have is this:

- Client  /   Model

  - A     /     1
  - A     /    1
  - B     /    1
  - B     /    1
  - C     /    2
  - D      /    1

And what I need to show is:

- Model   /    Total
- 1     /      3
- 2     /      1

The code I have is:

```
SELECT  Client, Model, COUNT(Model) Total
FROM    Table
GROUP BY Client, Model
```

but all this does is return every occurrence of both columns. Can anyone help, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you want to drop the Client in the group by and the select?

Answer (score 5):

To count the number of distinct clients per model:

```
SELECT  Model
,       COUNT(distinct Client) Total
FROM    Table
GROUP BY 
        Model
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a9ac/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

This is due by the Client in the group by. Exclude the Client from your query. Try this :

```
SELECT Model, COUNT(Model) Total
FROM Table
GROUP BY MODEL
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the number of "clients" for each model; so try this:

```
select model
     , count(distinct client) as Total
from   table
group by model
```